# Convert object attributes to dict

Tags: python

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        #other attributes
        self.children = [] #Child objects in self.children

    def convert(self):
        return vars(self)
```

When using `vars(foo)` or `foo.__dict__` the objects in `self.children` aren't converted into dictionaries too, returning a dictionary like this:

```
{'name': 'name', 'children': [object1,object2...]}
```

These 'child' objects are also instances of the foo class.
At first I tried using `dict['children'] = [vars(item) for item in dict['children']]` to convert these objects but unfortunately this doesn't work for children of children.
Is there a recursive function I can create to convert all these objects and their children?

Comment: What specific kinds of objects do you want to convert to a dict of their (recursively dictified) attributes, and which attributes do you want to include? Remember, lists are objects too, as are strings, but you're not converting those.

Comment: `vars` doesn't *convert to a dictionary*, it simply *returns the namespace of the argument*, which in Python, namespaces of user-defined objects are by default simply `dict` objects.

Comment: You need to write a recursive function that converts the current object to a dict, then calls itself on the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with a recursive function. Get the vars for the object, then replace the children list with a list of converted children.

```
def convert(self):
    d = dict(vars(self)) # Copy the vars() dictionary
    d['children'] = [c.convert() for c in self.children]
    return d
```